# What hash google chrome shows in developers console source tab for .gif images?

Tags: google-chrome, image-processing, hash, google-chrome-devtools, gif

[image: Highlighted screen shot provided.]

If you look at the image, I've opened the .gif image in developers console and I see a hash. Can somebody explain what is this hash. I've highlighted both the image file and hash in image.

The link i used : https://images.secureserver.net/rcc/extranet/Marketing/Banners/15733_Rslr399_120x90_blue.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a hash, but a Base64 encode of the binary file.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
```

This will show the same image when rendered.